# Getting a library with ndk-build and another with CMake build systems to work on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

The following is the structure of my app/src/main.

`nnl` is a library which internally uses `xerces`. Except that it doesn't have any dependencies. I got `xerces` from [here](https://github.com/pelya/commandergenius/tree/sdl_android/project/jni/xerces). I've used `api.h`, `Bridge.h` and `native-lib.cpp` in my CMakeLists.txt which will hopefully work once the `xerces` dependency is met.

How do I proceed from here? Where can I put the `xerces` library and which all config files do I need to change from here?

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── cpp
│   ├── api.h
│   ├── Bridge.cpp
│   ├── Bridge.h
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── native-lib.cpp
│   └── nnl
├── java
│   └── in
├── jni
│   └── xerces
```

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line. I might have a workaround for you.